# Fetching data from InputStream in java

Tags: java, android, inputstream, inputstreamreader

I am trying to fetch data from InputStream using InputStreamReader and my code is given below.

```
protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
    String result = "";
    URL url;
    HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;

    try {
        url = new URL(urls[0]);
        urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        InputStream in = urlConnection.getInputStream();
        InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(in);

        int data = reader.read();
        while (data != -1) {
            char current = (char) data;
            result += current;
            data = reader.read();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return result;
}
```

I am facing a problem in understanding, how does `result += current` statement work. Through my understanding, it seems `char current` data is being transferred to `result`, but `current` is an integer that cast into char, and if `current` is an integer that cast in char transferring to `result`. So, how I will be able to extract every line from InputStream as a result prints integer that casted into char not the lines from InputStream.

I know, I am thinking something wrong but I am unable to understand it.

Please help me to understand how this works :)

Comment: I would use a BufferedReader so that I could use BufferedReader#readLine().

Comment: What does the data look like that you get from the server?

Comment: Can you point out which part of the code that you don't understand?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are looking for

```
BufferedReader r = BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
List<String> lines  = r.readLines();
```

Comment: Thank you. But in above question, I am trying to understand the function of that particular code for curiosity. By the way, this code is simple and easily applicable, I would definately use BufferedReader in my project.